# Referencing an existing object in Nelmio's Alice

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, nelmio-alice

I'm configuring my *mock/dev* data with [Nelmio's Alice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice), so far so good.

I'm using [hautelook's AliceBundle](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) to get a nice integration with Symfony 3.1.

The problem I'm having is the one that follows:

I have a set of data is automatically generated and inserted in the Database by an external task, in one of the *Doctrine Objects* I need to reference one of those. I've already created the proper *Doctrine Entity* mapping the fields and the primary key but I can't figure how to reference one of those objects from my `students.yml`.

I've tried the following:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Student:
    clientApp1:
        name: George
        class: 3
        age: 20
        active: true
        groups: [1, 3]
```

Being groups `1` and `3` groups that the task has already inserted in the database.

I get the following **error** whenever I try to load my *fixtures* into the **database**:

```
~>bin/console hautelook_alice:doctrine:fixtures:load
```

> [Hautelook\AliceBundle\Alice\DataFixtures\LoadingLimitException]
>
> Loading files limit of 5 reached. Could not load the following files:
>
> /home/user/App/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/dev/students.yml:
>    - Entity with Id 1 and Class AppBundle\Entity\Group not found

I have just one file so the first part of the error makes no sense, I think it's more of a typo by their reporting system, but the second part is the one that bugs me... The primary key (Id) is correct but it does not find it.

I've been looking at the documentation but I've seen nothing related, any thoughts?

**EDIT:** I just realize that the command does **purge** the **database** so it becomes impossible for Alice to find *Group 1* nor *Group 2*. I'll try to workaround it and see if the command can be executed without the purging...

Comment: Hello! Try to use `bin/console hautelook_alice:doctrine:fixtures:load --append`. This will append your fixtures without purging the database.

Comment: Yes, that was it, the plain references work just fine and the problem was the purging I didn't take into account. Post answer so I can mark it as a resolved, I was going to answer it myself yesterday but I forgot to! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hautelook_alice:doctrine:fixtures:load` command purges the database, so, if you want to reference in your fixtures existed entity from database, you should append your fixtures. Flag `--append` do all the work.

`$ bin/console hautelook_alice:doctrine:fixtures:load --append`

Answer (score 0):

The error is on another fixture file: `src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/dev/students.yml:` but not the one you're expecting to be loaded: `alice-fixtures.yml` so just remove the first file and try to load your fixtures again: `bin/console h:d:f:l`